# How to include an Android layout but also access its elements in binding?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm doind this on my activity:

```
       <include
        android:id="@+id/withGyroLayout"
        layout="@layout/with_gyro_layout"/>
```

Where `with_gyro_layout.xml` is

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.util.FixedTransformerViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerTop"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="143dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.example.util.FixedTransformerViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerBottom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="143dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPagerTop" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

However, I can't access the elements `viewPagerBottom` or `viewPagerTop` from the binding for my activity:

```
binding.viewPagerBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
binding.viewPagerTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I tried putting `with_gyro_layout.xml` around `<merge>...</merge>` but it also didn't solve.

I want to be able to change programatically between `with_gyro_layout.xml` and `without_gyro_layout.xml` and also access its inner elements by the binding. How can I do that?

Comment: Please post complete layout code, including `<layout>` tags and how you initialize the bindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things are required in order to use ViewBinding with an included layout.

#### `<merge>` is not supported

The documentation only covers **Data Binding**, and not View Binding, but it does appear to be applicable to both. See https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#includes

> Data binding doesn't support include as a direct child of a merge element.

In other words, the layout must have a real, concrete view as its root element. The following is supported:

```
<LinearLayout ...>
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

But a layout with a `<merge>` root is not supported:

```
<merge ...>
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... />
</merge>
```

#### The `<include>` tag must specify an ID

It is, in general, possible to include a layout without explicitly specifying an ID. View Binding does not support this:

```
<include layout="@layout/included_layout"/>
```

Even if the included layout has an ID on its root element, it is still not supported. Instead, you must explicitly specify the ID on the `<include>` tag:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/some_id"
    layout="@layout/included_layout"/>
```

Once both of these conditions are satisfied, your generated binding for the outer layout will include a reference to the binding of the included layout. Let's say our two files are `outer_layout.xml` and `included_layout.xml`. Then these two files would be generated:

- `OuterLayoutBinding.java`
- `IncludedLayoutBinding.java`

And you could reference the included views like this:

```
val outerBinding = OuterLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val innerBinding = binding.someId // uses the id specified on the include tag
val innerView = innerBinding.viewPagerTop
```

Or, for short:

```
val binding = OuterLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
val innerView = binding.someId.viewPagerTop
```

Comment: I tried to import it but there is none. Even tried restarting Andrid Studio. Also, even if it generates, it wouldn't be the one inside the activity, I'd have to insert it manually, right? Is it possible?

Comment: there exists `binding.withGyroLayout` but `binding.withGyroLayout.viewPagerBottom` does not exist, maybe I need to use findViewById? Isn't there a way to use it as a binding?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I've updated my answer with a lot more detail. I was able to reproduce all of this in my own Android Studio (I'm using version 4.0).

Comment: I remember that binding.someId used to give me a reference of the included layout binding, but now for some reason, it is a LinearLayout (the parent element in the layout instead of the binding reference). Is the short syntax not working anymore?